Problema con actualizaciones de Material3 en jetpack compose
Buen día comunidad, estoy realizando una app simple, que vendría a ser una red social para Cinéfilos. El error que estoy teniendo por lo que estuve averiguando es por Material 3. No me reconoce algunos componentes
Este es el codigo de mi barra de navegacion:





import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.NavGraph.Companion.findStartDestination
import com.example.movieapp.presentation.navegation.AppScreens
import com.example.movieapp.ui.theme.Primario


@Composable
fun BottomNavigationBar(navController: NavController, items: List<AppScreens>) {
    val currentScreen = navController.currentDestination?.route ?: ""
    BottomNavigation(
        backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
        contentColor = Primario,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        items.forEach { screen ->
            BottomNavigationItem(
                icon = {
                    screen.icon?.let {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = it,
                            contentDescription = screen.title
                        )
                    }
                },
                label = { screen.title },
                selected = currentScreen == screen.route,
                onClick = {
                    navController.navigate(screen.route) {
                        popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                            saveState = true
                        }
                        launchSingleTop = true
                    }
                },
                alwaysShowLabel = false
            )
        }

    }
}

Y los errores que me esta dando son:
-Unresolved reference: BottomNavigation (Linea 18)
-Unresolved reference: BottomNavigationItem (Linea 24)
-@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function (Linea 27)
mi Build gradle se ve asi:
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")

//Dager hilt
    kotlin("kapt")
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")

    //parcelable para poder pasar objetos por paramentro cuando se quiera hacer navegacion con compose
    id("kotlin-parcelize")
    //Serealizacion
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.8.10"

}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.moobeez"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.moobeez"
        minSdk = 26
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.3"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.7.0")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2024.04.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")

    //Navegacion Compose
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.7")

    implementation("androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2024.04.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")

    // Fragment
    implementation ("androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.6.2")
    // Activity
    implementation ("androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.8.2")
    // ViewModel
    implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.7.0")
    // LiveData
    implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.7.0")
    implementation ("androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.6.5")
    implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.7.0")

    // Retrofit
    implementation ("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
    implementation ("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0")
    //Corrutinas
    implementation ("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.7.1")


    //Hilt
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.47")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.47")

    //coil
    implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.4.0")

    //Carrusel
    implementation("com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager:0.20.0")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-util:1.6.5")

    // -- Navigation
    implementation ("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.7")
    implementation ("com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material:1.6.5")
    //serializacion
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.5.1")

    //Fuentes Texto
    implementation ("androidx.compose.ui:ui-text-google-fonts:1.6.5")


    implementation ("androidx.window:window:1.2.0")
    implementation ("androidx.compose.material3:material3-window-size-class")

    //On Boarding
    implementation ("com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager:0.20.0")

    //Lottie
    implementation ("com.airbnb.android:lottie-compose:5.2.0")

    //Datastore
    implementation ("androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0")

}

Todo funciona correcto, solo que no me aparece la barra de navegacion y tambien de la nada todos los textos se pusieron en color negro en toda la app.
